# Switching order of maximization and integration

Tags: real-analysis

I have non-negative function $g(y,x)$ that is define using non-negative $f(y,x)$ in the following way:
\begin{align*}
g(y,x)=\int_{0}^x f(t,y) dt 
\end{align*}
I am  trying to maximize  $\max_{y \in S} g(y,x)$. Using Fatou's lemma we have that
\begin{align*}
\max_{y \in S} g(y,x)= \int_{0}^x f(t,y) dt \le \int_{0}^x \max_{y \in S}f(t,y) dt
\end{align*}

I also have that $\max_{y \in S}f(t,y) \le h(t)$ where  $\int_0^x h(t)  <\infty$

My question when does the last inequality hold with equally?

What do I have to assume about $f(y,x)$ and $g(x,y)$ for equality to hold?

Can I apply dominated convergence theorem here?

Comment: Depending on $S$ and $f$, $\max_{y\in S} f(t,y)$ needs not even be measurable. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y_n$ such that $g(y_n,x) \to \max_{y \in S} g(y,x)$.

Now you obtain under the assumption that $\sup_y f(t,y)$ is well behaved and bounded
$$\max_{y \in S} g(y,x) =\lim_n g(y_n,x) = \lim_n \int_0^x f(t, y_n)\, dt  = \int_0^x \lim_n f(t,y_n)\, dt$$

Therefore the equality 
\begin{align*}
\max_{y \in S} g(y,x)=\le \int_{0}^x \max_{y \in S}f(t,y) dt
\end{align*}
holds if $\lim_n f(t,y_n) = \sup_{y \in S}f(t,y) $.

Under the additional hypothesis that $S$ is compact. Then $y_n \to y^*$ follows without loss of generality and equality will hold if there is a $y^*$ such that $$ f(t,y^*) = \max_{y \in S}f(t,y)$$